# I am trying to add a Dropdown menu wit HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a dropdown menu to the dropdown class of my mini project. I have been able to do this for the second bar and it works but it is not working for the first one. I just started learning html, css and javascript and I am trying to replicate a hotel's homepage.

This is the HTML. I only included the dropdown menu part.

```
<div class = "dropdown">
      <a href="#">Currency</a>
    <div class ="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">Naira</a>
      <a href="">Dollar</a>
      <a href="">Euro</a>
      <a href="">Pound</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "dropdown2">
      <a href="#">Language</a>
    <div class ="dropdown-content2">
      <a href="">English</a>
      <a href="">French</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS. Only included stylings for the dropdown menu too.

```
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown-content{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a{
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 36px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;

}
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown-content{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content a{

  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;

}
.dropdown2{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.dropdown2 a{
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown-content2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content2 a{

  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

This is the Javascript. The second dropdown 2 works but the first does not.

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var content = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  if (content.style.display==='none') {
    content.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }

})



document.querySelector('.dropdown2').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var content2 = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content2');
  if (content2.style.display==='none') {
    content2.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    content2.style.display = 'none';
  }

})
```

Comment: That is because `content2.style.display` does not return the computed CSS style, but only returns the property set by the `style` attribute on the element itself. You might want to use a CSS class to toggle the display, then you can check if the element has the class or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `display: none;` from `.dropdown-content a{...}.
2. Place `display:none;` in the inline query for both `dropdown-content` and `dropdown-content2`.

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var content = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  if (content.style.display === 'none') {
    content.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }

});



document.querySelector('.dropdown2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var content2 = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content2');
  if (content2.style.display === 'none') {
    content2.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    content2.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 10px 36px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.dropdown2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "dropdown">
      <a href="#">Currency</a>
    <div class ="dropdown-content" style="display:none;">
      <a href="">Naira</a>
      <a href="">Dollar</a>
      <a href="">Euro</a>
      <a href="">Pound</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class = "dropdown2">
      <a href="#">Language</a>
    <div class ="dropdown-content2" style="display:none;">
      <a href="">English</a>
      <a href="">French</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this though but it did not work. I added the styles directly to the html elements and I am only getting the dropdown for the "dropdown2"

Comment: Thanks. I tried this though but it did not work. I added the styles directly to the html elements and I am only getting the dropdown for the "dropdown2"

Comment: Mean the snippet I added isn't it working as you asked?

Answer (score 0):

You should create two CSS classes to handle the behavior in your script.
Here's is en example:

`sample.html`

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dd1">
    Currency
    <div class="dropdown-content hidden" id="dc1">
        <a href="">Item 1</a>
        <a href="">Item 2</a>
        <a href="">Item 3</a>
        <a href="">Item 4</a>
        <a href="">Item 5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that containers has class hidden by default.

`sample.css`

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    border: 1px solid red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

Only use .hidden or .visible classes to display the container.
This brings a bit of scalability to your web, so you can standarize this dropdown behavior.

`sample.js`

```
changeClass = (id) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
    if (element.classList.contains('hidden')) 
        swapClasses(element.classList, 'hidden', 'visible');
    else 
        swapClasses(element.classList, 'visible', 'hidden');
};

swapClasses = (list, toRemove, toAdd) => {
    list.remove(toRemove);
    list.add(toAdd);
}

document.querySelector('#dd1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeClass('dc1');
});

document.querySelector('#dd2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeClass('dc2');
});
```

Hope it helps.
Any issue or question, please let me know.

Comment: Do I add the class of visible to second ID of the HTML. The one with the class of hidden.

Comment: You could replicate the #dd1 container with another key (#dd2, may be to match the sample.js)